# Animate div from top to middle of page only with Css without jquery or java script

Tags: html, css

i have to show text effects on page load of website i.e to Animate div from top to middle of page only with Css without jquery or java script.
my div css

```
#body_welcome_content{ width:450px; margin: 205px auto 0; font-size:48px; font-family: 'Playball', cursive; text-align:center; color:#FFF; margin-top:35px; text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #000;
```

}

help me out as new to CSS. also make sure for inter browser compatibility so that it works on all browsers.[Without jquery]
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do that using `@keyframes`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9HUsQ/)

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
    animation: centerme 2s;
    -webkit-animation: centerme 2s;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999; /* To ensure that box is always on the top */
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* So that box doesn't move back to default place*/
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes centerme {
    0%   {left: 0; top: 0;}
    100%  {left: 50%;top: 50%;margin-top: -150px;margin-left: -150px;}
    /* Left and Top are 50% with margins which are half of width and height */
}

@-webkit-keyframes centerme {
    0%   {left: 0;}
    100%  {left: 50%;margin-left: -150px;}
}
```